# Need info on block for a vinyl storage shed

Tags: foundation, storage

I am putting up a 10 w by 8 deep vinyl shed. My intent is to build the base out of concrete block. I am want to put a solid base of block. I am then going to put 1/2 in thick pressure treated sheets of plywood on top and anchor the bldg to the plywood. My main questions are. DO I need I anchor the wood to anything? And how do I figure out how many block do I need for a solid foundation,

Comment: That's not a typical floor design. It'll be difficult to keep the block flat enough even if you used 3/4" plywood, which is why most shed floors are framed with lumber. I'll be surprised if you get a definitive answer considering the abnormal approach and the fact that it's entirely up to you.

Comment: Anchoring the shed to the wood only is basically anchoring it to nothing at all, even if you put something heavy inside. Be prepared to watch it sail away in the next big wind storm.

Comment: What if I anchor the shed  to the wood and then anchor everything to the neighboring trees and fence?